# 1С-Битрикс - как вывести поле НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ

Tags: битрикс

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести поле НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ. Я воспользовался примером (ниже), но в результате получаю массив непонятной конструкции, что за элементы со знаком "~". Может найдутся знатоки "Битрикс".

Пример:

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME"); 
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $IBLOCK_ID, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y"); 
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect); 
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) { 
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields(); 
    print_r($arFields); 
}
```

Массив на выходе:

```
Array ( [ID] => 1 [~ID] => 1 [NAME] => Текст 1 [~NAME] => Текст 1 )  Array ( [ID] => 2 [~ID] => 2 [NAME] => Текст 2 [~NAME] => Текст 2 )  Array ( [ID] => 3 [~ID] => 3 [NAME] => Текст 3 [~NAME]
=> Текст 3 )
```

Хочу получить один массив такого вида:

```
Array 
( 
    [NAME] => Текст 1
    [NAME] => Текст 2
    [NAME] => Текст 3
)
```

Comment: Честно сказать битриком никогда не пользовался но осмелюсь заявить, что если вы переменной $arSelect присвоите значение Array("NAME")  а не Array("ID","NAME") то вы и получите тот массив, который вам нужен. Хотя наверное там всё же будут элементы с индексом "~NAME", не знаю.

Comment: да пробовал так, но тогда получаю массив как в первом примере, но тольке именна элементов NAME а значение остается ID? вот такой вот битрикс :(

Comment: переменные "~NAME" и "~ID" - это теже значения полей, но не безопасные для отображения. т.е. например теги там не фильтруются. а чтоб вывести NAME, надо делать как говорит KryDos.

Comment: и такой массив
    Array 
    ( 
        [NAME] => Текст 1
        [NAME] => Текст 2
        [NAME] => Текст 3
    )
у тебя не получится. потому что ключи должны быть разные

Answer (score 4, accepted):

сделай так:

```
$arResult = Array();
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME"); 
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $IBLOCK_ID, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y"); 
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect); 
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) { 
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields(); 
    array_push($arResult, $arFields['NAME']);
}
print_r($arResult);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало :)

Comment: это магия ))